# PayPal Server Side integration not passing payment details to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

Why am I not getting the response with the capture details on the client side?

I am trying to implement a server side integration for PayPal's smart buttons. I have tried a few different methods, and this is the method I have had the most success with.

However, it still doesn't appear to be working 100%. Atm, clicking a button opens the payment window, I can login with the sandbox personal account, go through the checkout flow, and then I get the standard alert, but for some reason I am not getting the desired response from the server.

When I sign into sandbox paypal, on the personal account, I can see the transactions being sent successfully (they are pending, awaiting confirmation from the merchant). When I sign into the sandbox merchant account, there are no transactions available. When I take the order ID from the smart button, and send it to PayPal's api route to get the order details, it comes back as captured and completed.

Has anyone else experienced something similar with the payments not showing up on the merchant sandbox account? If I sign into the developer account, and look at the API log, I can see the orders being created and captured successfully, but they still don't show up on the merchant account.

### Here's my server side code:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

// 1. Set up your server to make calls to PayPal

// 1a. Import the SDK package
const paypal = require("@paypal/checkout-server-sdk");

// 1b. Import the PayPal SDK client that was created in `Set up Server-Side SDK`.
/**
 *
 * PayPal HTTP client dependency
 */
const payPalClient = require("./PayPalConfig");

// route to set up a transaction
router.post("/orders/create", async (req, res) => {
  // 3. Call PayPal to set up a transaction
  const request = new paypal.orders.OrdersCreateRequest();
  request.prefer("return=representation");
  request.requestBody({
    intent: "CAPTURE",
    purchase_units: [
      {
        amount: {
          currency_code: "USD",
          value: "4.20",
        },
      },
    ],
  });

  let order;
  try {
    order = await payPalClient.client().execute(request);
  } catch (err) {
    // 4. Handle any errors from the call
    console.error(err);
    return res.sendStatus(500);
  }

  // 5. Return a successful response to the client with the order ID
  res.json({
    orderID: order.result.id,
  });
  console.log(order.result.id);
});

// route to handle capturing of orders
router.post("/orders/capture", async (req, res) => {
  // const captureDetails
  let captureDetails = "";
  // 2a. Get the order ID from the request body
  const orderID = req.body.orderID;
  // 3. Call PayPal to capture the order
  const request = new paypal.orders.OrdersCaptureRequest(orderID);
  request.requestBody({});

  try {
    const capture = await payPalClient.client().execute(request);

    // 4. Save the capture ID to your database. Implement logic to save capture to your database for future reference.
    const captureID = capture.result.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id;
    captureDetails = capture.result;
    // await database.saveCaptureID(captureID);
    res.json(captureDetails);
  } catch (err) {
    // 5. Handle any errors from the call
    console.error(err);
    return res.sendStatus(500);
  }

  // 6. Return a successful response to the client
  // res.sendStatus(200).json({ details: captureDetails });
  res.json({ details: captureDetails });
});

module.exports = router;
```

### Here's my client side code:

```
// Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
paypal
  .Buttons({
    // Call your server to set up the transaction
    createOrder: function (data, actions) {
      return fetch("http://localhost:3000/payment/paypal/orders/create", {
        method: "post",
      })
        .then(function (res) {
          return res.json();
        })
        .then(function (orderData) {
          return orderData.orderID;
          console.log(orderData.orderID);
        });
    },

    // Call your server to finalize the transaction
    onApprove: function (data) {
      return fetch("http://localhost:3000/payment/paypal/orders/capture", {
        method: "post",
        headers: {
          "content-type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          orderID: data.orderID,
        }),
      })
        .then(function (res) {
          return res;
        })
        .then(function (details) {
          console.log(details);
          alert("Transaction funds captured from " + details.payer_given_name);
        });
    },
  })
  .render("#paypal-button-container");
```

### Here's the details being logged from the client

```
Response {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:3000/payment/paypal/orders/capture", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "cors"
url: "http://localhost:3000/payment/paypal/orders/capture"
__proto__: Response
```

Answer (score 0):

On the server side, don't specify 'details' as a key.

res.json(captureDetails);

---

You need to return res.json() on the client side. It hasn't parsed the json object.

---

> When I sign into the sandbox merchant account, there are no
> transactions available. When I take the order ID from the smart
> button, and send it to PayPal's api route to get the order details, it
> comes back as captured and completed.

You are signing in to the wrong sandbox merchant account. The correct one will depend on the sandbox clientId you are using.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I am not signing into the wrong sandbox merchant account. I only have two sandbox accounts, one merchant, one customer. The merchant email that paypal generates, is the email I am using to sign in, and it matches the email shown on the pending payments on the customer account.

Comment: If you believe you are signing into the correct account but the payments aren't there, then the payments were sent to an unconfirmed email in sandbox, and so aren't in fact in that account. They are pending unclaimed, and will be returned in 30 days if left unclaimed on that email.  Confirm the email in a sandbox account via https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessprofile/settings/email and https://developer.paypal.com/developer/notifications/